# Find a specific string in php with empty right side

Tags: php

This is my code

```
if (strpos($rSelect['date'],'شنبه') !== FALSE) {}
```

as you can see, It looks for "شنبه" and it **returns !== FALSE** when it gets this word.
but i want to get !==FALSE when it finds 'شنبه' and there is no other word right side of "شنبه".

Comment: so do you want to match it against last word?

Comment: Yes, It should be the last word.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how will it work with non-ASCII characters, but you could try

```
if(preg_match('/شنبه$/', $rSelect['date']) > 0)
```